# Having trouble using tkinter in python to create a simple gui for my simple chatbot

Tags: python, tkinter, chatbot

So... i am wanting to turn my console chatbot into a GUI chatbot and whenever i do it seems to never be working... ill paste an original code(which runs in console) then i will paste the same code but added some tkinter codes to turn it into gui instead of console app(just clarifying again, my gui code really doesnt work). what was my mistake in the gui code and how to make it work.

```
import random
#THIS IS THE CONSOLE APP CODE
greetings = ['hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!','hey']
random_greeting = random.choice(greetings)

question = ['How are you?','How are you doing?']
responses = ['Okay',"I'm fine"]
random_response = random.choice(responses)


while True:
    userInput = input(">>> ")
    if userInput in greetings:
        print(random_greeting)
    elif userInput in question:
        print(random_response)
    else:
        print("I did not understand what you said")
```

alright here is the potential gui code that i tried

```
import random
import tkinter
#GUI CODE
t = tkinter.Tk()
userInput = tkinter.Entry(t)
userInput.pack()
def cb():
    greetings = ['hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!','hey']
    random_greeting = random.choice(greetings)

    question = ['How are you?','How are you doing?']
    responses = ['Okay',"I'm fine"]
    random_response = random.choice(responses)


    while True:
        if 'hello' in userInput.get():
            lab = tkinter.Label(t,text =random_greeting)
            lab.pack()
        elif 'how are you' in userInput.get():
            labb = tkinter.Label(t,text =random_response)
            labb.pack()
        else:
            labc = tkinter.Label(t,text ="I did not understand what you said")
            labc.pack()
button = tkinter.Button(t, text="Enter",command=  cb)
button.pack()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

( the purpose of this chatbot code is really so i could understand GUI more)
Thanks!

Comment: you don't need a while loop since the user press the button to trigger the function, also the first test was better : `if userInput in greetings:`, keep this pattern like `if userInput.get() in greetings:`

Comment: And you shouldn't be creating new Label widgets all the time. Just update the text in the Label using its `.config` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of room for improvement in this code, but this should get you heading in the right direction.

It's a common convention in well-written Tkinter code to do `import tkinter as tk`. That lets us write `tk` instead of `tkinter`, which saves typing, and makes it easy to change the code to run on Python 2 if we need to do that: just change the import statement to `import Tkinter as tk`. And it's *much* better than doing `from tkinter import *`, because it lets us see what names we've imported from Tkinter, and it doesn't dump over a hundred names into our namespace.

As PRMoureu mentioned in the comments, we don't want a `while` loop in the callback function: we just need to respond to the string that's in the Entry widget when the user presses the button.

We create a single Label widget to hold the bot's response text, and we can update it with the Label`s`.config` method.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
user_input = tk.Entry(root)
user_input.pack()

greetings = ['hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!', 'hey']
question = ['How are you?', 'How are you doing?']
responses = ['Okay', "I'm fine"]
huh = "I did not understand what you said"

def cb():
    user_text = user_input.get()
    if user_text in greetings:
        bot_text = random.choice(greetings)
    elif user_text in question:
        bot_text = random.choice(responses)
    else:
        bot_text = huh
    output.config(text=bot_text)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=cb)
button.pack()

output = tk.Label(root, text='')
output.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

It takes a little while to get used to GUI programming, because the control flow is not what you're used to from console programming. With code that runs in the console, the code does what it wants to do, when it wants to do it, and the user responds. In GUI code, we set everything up and then wait for events generated by the user's actions, and then our code responds to those actions. This is called [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Although it can be a bit disorienting at first, with practice you'll soon get the hang of it. ;)

---

We don't really need that button. Instead, we can bind our callback to the Entry widget so that it's called when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed inside the Entry widget. We have to modify the signature of the callback because it will now receive an Event object when it's called. But we don't need to change anything inside the callback function body because we aren't actually using the data in the Event object.

Here's the new version:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
user_input = tk.Entry(root)
user_input.pack()

greetings = ['hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!', 'hey']
question = ['How are you?', 'How are you doing?']
responses = ['Okay', "I'm fine"]
huh = "I did not understand what you said"

def cb(event):
    user_text = user_input.get()
    if user_text in greetings:
        bot_text = random.choice(greetings)
    elif user_text in question:
        bot_text = random.choice(responses)
    else:
        bot_text = huh
    output.config(text=bot_text)

user_input.bind("<Return>", cb)
output = tk.Label(root, text='')
output.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```